# Adding numerical values from dict to a new column in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am practicing machine learning and working with a movie/rating dataset. I am trying to create a new column in the dataframe which numerically identifies each genre (around 1300 of them). My logic was to create a dictionary of the unique genres and label with a integer. Then create a for loop to iterate through each row of the dataframe, checking the genre of each, then assigning its appropriate value to a new column named "genre_Id". However this has been causing a infinite loop in which I can not even break with ctrl-c. Same issue when working in Jupyter ( Interrupt Kernel fails to stop it). Below is a summarized version of my approach.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

movies_data = pd.read_csv("C://mypython/moviedata/movies.csv")
ratings_data = pd.read_csv("C://mypython/moviedata/ratings.csv")

joined = pd.merge(movies_data,ratings_data, how = 'inner', on=['movieId'])

print(joined.head())
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format

genres = joined['genres'].unique()


genre_dict = {}
Id = 1
for i in genres:
    genre_dict[i] = Id
    Id += 1

joined['genre_id'] = 0    

increment = 0
for i in joined['genres']:
    if i in genre_dict:
        joined['genre_id'][increment] = genre_dict[i]
        increment += 1
```

I know I should probably be taking a smaller sample to work with as there is about 20,000,000 rows in the dataset but I figured I'd try this as a exercise.
I also recieve the "setting values from copy warning" though this hasn't caused me issues in the past for my other projects. Any thoughts on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT** Found a solution using the Series map feature.

joined['genre_id'] = joined.genres.map(genre_dict)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no permission to just comment. This is a suggestion and right procedure to handle categorical values in a dataset. You can use inbuilt [sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) function which do the work you wanted to do.
For better understanding with examples check this [One Hot Encode Sequence Data in Python](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-one-hot-encode-sequence-data-in-python/). Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I actually just found the solution. joined['genre_id'] = joined.genres.map(genre_dict)

Comment: @stephenbarter Actually I used to do like this when I encounter categorical values to apply for ML algorithms,but When the the categorical values are like more than 5 or 6 columns it is difficult time consuming to make dictionaries and use them. Instead OneHotEncoder is the best solution for that.If you figured it out I will delete the answer.

Comment: I believe you are correct. That option would work as well. Thanks

Comment: You are Welcome. @stephenbarter